# Commands out of sync USING MYSQL ODBC CONNECTOR

Tags: mysql, odbc

When calling an select statement after cursor operation I get : commands out of sync , you can't run this command now.  The below is just a rough snippet of store procedure for testing purpose.
If it uses a cursor but does no "SELECT" statement, everything works.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestOne()
BEGIN
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
DECLARE cur_textCursor CURSOR FOR ( SELECT 1 );
OPEN cur_textCursor ; 
IF done THEN
CLOSE textCursor ;
 END IF;
SELECT 1;
END
```

> Using MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver
>
> MySQL version 5.5

**Update :**

The above issue works fine in My Sql ODBC Connector 5.1 Driver.

It is still a bug in My Sql ODBC Connector 5.3 ANSI Driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open bug about this issue here:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71431

It seems that while your case works in Connector/ODBC 5.1, in version 5.2 and 5.3 you need to wrap the additional query inside a BEGIN..END block.

This is probably a bug that could be fixed, but the easy workaround is to wrap it as above or use Connector/ODBC 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

This fix for me:
ODBC -> tab System DSN -> double click to configure my data source -> details -> tab Cursors -> **Uncheck** [Don't cache results of forward-only cursors] -> click Ok